# Create borders around controls in MFC Form

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an MFC form, basic stuff, a few group boxes, a few text boxes, some buttons, and a list box. What I'd like to do is add a border around all of it, preferably without a group box. Like, drawing lines along the right areas. I was told this is bad to do on a dialog though. What would I need to go about doing something like that?

I am currently using MFC C++ with Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: A group box is the standard visual cue for grouping elements. Why not simply go with that, and have a consistent UI today, and tomorrow.

Comment: Because sadly that's not how the last guy had things working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a Picture control to the dialog and set the style to have a border only. If the control has a width or height of 0 you can get a single line. Doing it in the dialog editor will only give you positioning down to the dialog unit, if you need pixel level control you'll have to create or reposition it in `OnInitDialog`.